# how to get first and last date of the current year javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to get the first and last date of the current year. Example in this format: 2020-01-01 and 2020-12-31. Thanks!

I have this initial code that gets the current date today. This might help.

```
var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can calculate the current date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

You can instantiate `Date` using year, month and day, but keep in mind that month is indexed from 0:

```
var theFirst = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var theLast = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the first date of the current year as follows.

```
var d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
```

You can get the last date of the current year as follows.

```
var d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a lot like homework, so I'm not going to give you a code block to copy and paste.

You seem to already know how to get the current year, and the year always goes from 01-01 to 12-31. So do what you already have, but instead of today's date, use 01-01 and 12-31